# How to fix stuck Unity "converting managed assemblies to c++"?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

In Unity 5.5.4 (on Windows 10 x64) when going to File -> build settings, chose WEBGL, clicked build, the loading stuck at "converting managed assemblies to c++".

Anyone knows the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off realtime protection in antivirus unstucked it.